# Servo's aren't moving correctly

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino-uno, hc-05

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>  // servo library
Servo servo1;  // servo control object
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(5, 6); // RX, TX
int servo1Pin = 11;
int servo2Pin = 10;
int servo3Pin = 9;
int motor1pin = 8;
int flag = 0; //Sets integer for HIGH or LOW LED case
String bdata = "";
char c = ' ';

void setup()
{
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
  pinMode(motor1pin, OUTPUT);
  servo1.attach(servo1Pin);
  servo2.attach(servo2Pin);
  servo3.attach(servo3Pin);
}

void loop()
{
  int position;
  while (bluetooth.available()) {
    c = bluetooth.read();
    bdata += c;

    //~~~~~~Servo 1~~~~~~~~
    if (bdata == "open1")
    {
      //Opens Door
      for (position = 0; position < 90; position += 1)
      {
        servo1.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }
    if (bdata == "close1")
    {
      //Closes Door
      for (position = 90; position >= 0; position -= 1)
      {
        servo1.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }
    //~~~~~~Servo 2~~~~~~~~
    if (bdata == "open2")
    {
      //Opens Door
      for (position = 0; position < 90; position += 1)
      {
        servo2.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }
    if (bdata == "close2")
    {
      //Closes Door
      for (position = 90; position >= 0; position -= 1)
      {
        servo2.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }

    //~~~~~~Servo 3~~~~~~~~
    if (bdata == "open3")
    {
      //Opens Door
      for (position = 0; position < 90; position += 1)
      {
        servo3.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }
    if (bdata == "close3")
    {
      //Closes Door
      for (position = 90; position >= 0; position -= 1)
      { 

        servo3.write(position);  // Move to next position
        delay(20);               // Short pause to allow it to move
      }
    }
    //~~~~~~Motor 1~~~~~~
      if (bdata == "on")
    {
      flag = 1; //Turns LEDs on using a high digital signal
    }
    if (bdata == "off")
    {
      flag = 0; //Turns LEDs off using a low digital signal
    }

  }
  digitalWrite(motor1pin, flag);
  delay(1000);
  bdata = "";
}
```

It is uploaded to an Arduino Uno where I have the 3 servos and DC Motor connected via breadboard. It is meant to power a 3d printed mechanical arm I have made. when read you can see it is also controlled via Bluetooth using a HC-05 module and phone. I am having trouble with it as the commands for servo 1 are working fine so is 3, but when command for servo 2 is sent from phone servo 3 moves instead and servo 3 command also moves servo 3. I have already tried looking at the variable and the commands on my phone by nothing is sticking out to me. so here I am.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You're not clearing bdata, Try bdata = "", after every successful comparison.

Comment: Your code here looks fine to me, I can't see any typos or anything. It could be made more efficient, but that can wait. I would add some logging to verify what's being received; I can only think that the data being sent over the Bluetooth link isn't what you're expecting. Try adding a `Serial.println("Command received was: " + bdata);` just before the `delay(1000)` and see what's coming through.